# C++ find keys and values in a multimap

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, iterator

I want to create a structure that holds distinct strings and assign to each one of them some (not one unique) int values. After I have filled that structure, I want to check for each string how many different int have been assigned to and which exactly are they. I know that it is possible to tackle this with a multimap. However I am not sure if (or how) it is possible to get all the distinct strings contained to the multimap, since the function “find” requires a parameter for matching, while I do not know when searching which distinct values could be in the multimap. How could this be done with a multimap?

As an alternative solution I tried to use a simple map with a vector  as value. However I still cannot make this work because the iterator of the vector does not seem to be recognized and it indicates me : iterator must a have a pointer to class type.

```
map<string, vector<int>>::iterator multit;
int candID1, candID2, candID3;

for(multit=Freq.begin(); multit!=Freq.end(); multit++)
{
    if((*multit).second.size()==3)
    {
        vector<int> vectorWithIds = (*multit).second;

        for(vector<int>::iterator it = vectorWithIds.begin();
            it != vectorWithIds.end();it++)
        {
            candID1 = it->        Problem: The iterator is not recognized
        }
    }

}
```

Could anyone detect the problem? Is there an attainable solution, either on the first or the second way?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `*it` inside the for loop instead of `it->`?

Comment: Your sample is a really bad design, try to use the stl like for_each with a functor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `it->`? It's vector if `int`s, you probably want `*it`.

P.S. I have to admit I haven't read the whole prose.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a `multimap<string, int>`. Assuming I understood your requirements correctly, with you having "unique" strings and several different values for them. You could use `count(key)` to see how many values there are for a key and `equal_range(key)` which returns a `pair<interator, iterator>` with the first iterator pointing to the start of the range of values for a key and second iterator pointing past the value for key.

See [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is totaly not efficient at all, but you can use std::set initialized with you std::vector to extract only the unique values of std::vector, like in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main() {
    // some data
    std::string keys[] = {"first", "second", "third"};
    int values[] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 9};

    // initial data structures
    std::vector<std::string> words(keys, keys + sizeof(keys) / sizeof(std::string));
    std::vector<int> numbers(values, values + sizeof(values) / sizeof(int));

    // THE map
    std::map< std::string, std::vector<int> > dict;

    // inserting data into the map
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = words.begin(); itr != words.end(); itr++) {
        dict.insert(std::pair< std::string, std::vector<int> > (*itr, numbers));
    } // for

    // SOLUTION
    // count unique values for the key of std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >::iterator mtr;
    for(mtr = dict.begin(); mtr != dict.end(); mtr++) {
        std::set<int> unique((*mtr).second.begin(), (*mtr).second.end());
        std::cout << unique.size() << std::endl;
    } // for

    return 0;
} // main
```